# ASP.NET Server is showing different result that in my developer machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, telerik

Can someone please explain reason behind this issue. I am using telerik RadListView.

Here is the code

```
protected void radlistview_ItemDataBound(object sender, RadListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Item is RadListViewDataItem)
                {
                    var item = (RadListViewDataItem)e.Item;
                    var dataitem = item.DataItem;
                    if (dataitem == null) return;
                    t = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var clt in item.Controls)
                    {
                        t.AppendLine(clt.GetType().FullName + " - ");
                    }
                    Session["EcnLoadError"] = t.ToString();
                    ShowErrorAndExit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Session["EcnLoadError"] = ex.ToString();
                ShowErrorAndExit();
            }            
        }
```

My developer machine gives me the following result,

```
System.Web.UI.LiteralControl - 
System.Web.UI.LiteralControl - 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image - 
System.Web.UI.LiteralControl - 
System.Web.UI.LiteralControl - 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton - 
System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl -
```

But after deploying to server it gives me the following,

```
System.Web.UI.ResourceBasedLiteralControl - 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image - 
System.Web.UI.ResourceBasedLiteralControl - 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton - 
System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl -
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the rendered output of **LiteralControl** is more than 255 bytes, **ResourceBasedLiteralControl** is used for efficiency.

[ResourceBasedLiteralControl and why it exists](http://dpnikolaenko.blogspot.com/2004/08/resourcebasedliteralcontrol-and-why-it.html)

Comment: This is fine. By why Image control appears third when i run in my developer machine and after deploying on server it appears as second.

Comment: It is because because two **LiteralControl** are combined into a single **ResourceBasedLiteralControl**.